# how to prevent php script and mysql database from creating another row

Tags: php, mysql

from my application folder the first file which is a user authentication form get the information of the user and stores its into a database while the second file contains a series of multiple checkbox and time which get the information of the selected checkbox and time and save it in another row.

Explanation:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
        email        | password | checkbox1 | checkbox2 ! 
---------------------------------------------------------
 1. ***@gmail.com    |  ******  |           |           |
---------------------------------------------------------
 2.                  |          | Mon,Tue   | 20:30     |  
---------------------------------------------------------
```

please can anyone help me to provide a solution to prevent the second file from creating a new row, i want the whole information to be in one row . thanks a lot

Comment: we cant help if you dont show us your code

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: How about using `UPDATE` in SQL?

Comment: Is this real people, or some kind of test code? Did you just post Benard's password on the internet?

Comment: Are you storing the passwords in plain text? _**Don't do that!**_ Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a hash and store that. Then use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: thanks a lot guys i have resolved the problem